# Running Maven Goals in CLI

Tags: maven-2, command-line-interface

I have a maven pom.xml file with multiple instances of a same goal defined (inside `<execution>` with different `<id>`s).

I'm wondering how I can run a specific goal via maven command line. I've tried mvn --help, but  I couldn't find an entry regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question is always fun, especially the answer is "no, you can't do it."

After many Google searches, I've encountered the following article:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Default+Plugin+Execution+IDs

> There is no way to separate configurations for command line executions of different goals in the same plugin.
>   Currently, the main plugin configuration section can be used to define settings to be used when executing a plugin from the command line. Unfortunately, these settings are applied to all executions of the plugin.

Comment: Of course, if anyone want to prove me wrong, please do so, because it will really help me if this feature is present.

Answer (score 0):

Having read your own answer, I'm not sure I understood the question :) But it sounds like this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252359/is-it-possible-to-single-out-and-run-a-specific-goal-bound-to-a-maven-phase/) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252359/is-it-possible-to-single-out-and-run-a-specific-goal-bound-to-a-maven-phase/2254630#2254630).